# Laravel 5.2, why does 'npm install' NOT install laravel-elixir?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-elixir

I have to manually run `npm install laravel-elixir` with every new project.

Laravel project created by running `composer create-project laravel/laravel`

package.json contains:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#installation

Comment: I've followed this to the letter. npm install runs, but does not install the elixir package

Comment: There must be some errors thrown in the console. Those would be helpful if you have them. Have you tried sudo npm install just to make sure it's not a permissions issue?

Comment: do you use vangrant or homestead? if yes, there are problems with the filesystem paths. See this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7314